# AES-GCM JavaScript Implementation

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

I'm trying to write a javascript method which can decrypt the cipher text using AES-GCM 128bit key. I was able to write a java method, but facing some issues with the js code. Tried a lot, but couldn't spot the issue.

**Java method (works)**

Since, the cipherText ByteBuffer consists of (IV Length (represented as integer: 4 bytes) + IV (12 bytes) + cipherText), hence we decrypt in the same order.

```
   public String decrypt(final String ciphertext, final String encryptionKey) {
        try {
            final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(Base64.getDecoder().decode(ciphertext));
            final int ivLength = byteBuffer.getInt();
            final byte[] iv = new byte[ivLength];
            byteBuffer.get(iv);
            final byte[] cipherText = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
            byteBuffer.get(cipherText);

            final SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), AES);
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv));
            final byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);

            return new String(decryptedBytes);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            return StringUtils.EMPTY;
        }
    }
```

**Javascript method**

```
  const decrypt = (encData) => {
    const encryptedBuffer = Buffer.from(encData, 'base64');

    // Extract iv length (4 bytes) from the beginning
    const ivLength = encryptedBuffer.readUInt32BE(0);

    // Extract iv based on the iv length
    const iv = encryptedBuffer.slice(4, 4 + ivLength);

    // Extract the encrypted data (excluding IV and authentication tag)
    const enc = encryptedBuffer.slice(4 + ivLength, encryptedBuffer.length - 16);

    // Extract the authentication tag (last 16 bytes)
    const authTag = encryptedBuffer.slice(encryptedBuffer.length - 16);

    // Create a decipher instance
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(ALGO, key, iv);
    decipher.setAuthTag(authTag);

    // Decrypt the data
    let decryptedBytes = decipher.update(enc.toString('base64'), 'base64', 'utf8');
    decryptedBytes += decipher.final('utf8');

    return decryptedBytes;
  };

  return {
    decrypt,
  };
};
```

It is giving this generic error: `Error: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data at Decipheriv.final (internal/crypto/cipher.js:174:29)`.

I tried debugging but couldn't find the exact issue. I think I'm missing something when dealing with the first 4 bytes (the iv length). Any suggestions/advice would be great.

Comment: Your question is a good example of why you should post test data and the full code. The bug is in the NodeJS code part you didn't post: both the encoding of the key and the definition of `ALGO` are missing. The Java code does not do a Base64 decoding of the key, but UTF-8 encodes it, i.e. you apply a 24 bytes key and AES-192. If this is also done in the NodeJS code, it works: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/LHH. Note: The cleaner fix would be to do a Base64 decoding of the key in the Java code, so that AES-128 is used (which was probably intended).

Comment: Thank you so much @Topaco! Got it! The reason the key size is getting extended to 24 bytes and AES algorithm to 192 is because of the fact that the decoding of the key was not done properly. Also, why doesn't this 192 is needed in case of the java decrypt method?

Comment: Java (JCA/JCE) uses the key size to identify the respective AES variant (16 bytes -> AES-128, 24 bytes -> AES-192, 32 bytes -> AES-256) while in NodeJS/crypto code the algorithm must be *explicitly* specified (and key lengths different from this cause an error). So the reason is simply how it is implemented in the respective library.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much @Topaco for the explanations and helping me out!